# Execute native sql with hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using `hibernate 4.2.6` and `PostgreSQL 9.1`
I've been trying to execute sql query with hibernate. I've written:

```
Session session = Hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO products (name,cost) VALUES('%s',%s);", product.getName(), product.getCost());
createSQLQuery(sql);//has no effect. Query doesn't execute.
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

This query does not executed in DB. But if I write

```
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO products (name,cost) VALUES('%s',%s);", product.getName(), product.getCost());
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", "postgres");
connectionProps.put("password", "123");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/solid",connectionProps);
conn.createStatement().execute(sql);
```

corresponding row will add to table. Why hibernate doesn't work, but native query wth JDBC works?

Comment: What is your `createSQLQuery` method doing?

Comment: @BheshGurung It is _hibernate_ method. I think that this method execute native query.

Comment: It should be something like `session.createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate()`. That's why I asked, may be something missing in your posted code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should help you.

```
Session session = Hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO products (name,cost) VALUES('%s',%s);",product.getName(), product.getCost());
session.createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: I would assume that `cost` is a numeric column and numbers don't need single quotes.

Comment: Why do you use %s than.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, cost is integer.

Comment: And also if it does not work please post the content of createSQLQuery() method.

Comment: createSQLQuery() is _hibernate_ internal method. http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-query-example/

Comment: Than use Session object to create it. Simply doing createSqlQuery(sql) should give you compile time error.

Comment: I have made the edit. Your code should look like that.

Comment: `createSQLQuery()` is deprecated since hibernate 5.2. Now you should use `createNativeQuery()` instead

Answer (score 15):

It's always better to use PreparedStatement *(You don't want to give way to SQL Injections)*.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO products (name,cost) VALUES (?,?)";

Session sess = Hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Connection con = sess.connection();
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

pstmt.setString(1, product.getName());
pstmt.setInt(2, product.getCost());

pstmt.executeUpdate();

con.commit();
pstmt.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

Another issue that might hit you (like it hit me) is this:

You want to run a native query, but can't get it to work in your production code? Pay attention if you are using a different database user for the application than the schema owner. In that case you may have to add the schema prefix to the referenced tables in order to make it work.

In my example I am using an entity manager instead of the session:

```
String sql = "select id from some_table";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
List<Long> results = query.getResultList();
```

if some_table is owned by e.g. dba while the application is running as user, you will need to modify the query to:

```
String sql = "select id from dba.some_table";
```

Having Hibernate set to prefix all tables with

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dba</prop>
```

does apparently NOT affect native queries.

Answer (score 4):

worked with me in spring-boot and hibernate 5.4.2 using the entity manager

```
 @Autowired
EntityManager em;

public List<String> getDistinctColumnValues(String tableName, String columnName) {

    List<String> result = em.createNativeQuery("select distinct (" + columnName + ") from " + tableName).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that work for me is the following:

```
public List<T> queryNativeExecute(String query) throws CustomException {
        List<T> result =null;
        Session session =null;
        Transaction transaction=null; 
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionJavaConfigFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception exception){
            result=null;
            if (transaction !=null && transaction.isActive()){
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new CustomException(exception.getMessage(),exception,error.ErrorCode.DATABASE_TABLE,this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }finally{
            if (session !=null){
                session.close();    
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```