# Stored procedure is hitin when debugging. But it is not working(Data is n ot inserting to the database)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven

This is the code where i call the stored procedure in mysql.

```
public void createWallet(String number) {
    Query query= getSession().createSQLQuery("CALL createWalletForOrigin(:string_number)").addEntity(Wallet.class)
    .setParameter("string_number", number);

}
```

And hear is my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createWalletForOrigin`(IN string_number varchar(19))
BEGIN
insert into wallet values(string_number,0);
END
```

I cannot figure out why this is not executing. When i debug the method is calling successfully.

Comment: is that whole content of `createWallet` method ? if yes, you are missing db session and `query.executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not commiting a transaction.

```
getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
getSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

Take a look at this question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24782788/2019964) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: That is the actual reason. Thank you very much for helping to figure out the problem.